# Retrieving the current location of the user/ retrieving the values of longitude and latitude watchkit/ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, location, watchkit

I want to obtain the current location (longitude and latitude) of the user, but I just get 0 for both of the variables. I do not know where the problem lies in. I am following this tutorial and have updated the infop.list of the app folder and the watch extension folder (NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription), inserted the needed Watchconnector to both of the folders with cocoapods, and I also have added the Corelocation framework via link binary with libraries. 
I have little knowledge about swift and watch os, I hope anyone can help.
Here is the project file:  https://ufile.io/l5elkpsw

Thank you very much.

And here are my Appdelegate and Interfacecontroller file:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit



@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate  {
    let locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation = CLLocation()

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        WatchConnector.shared.activateSession()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestLocation()
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        return true
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if locations.count == 0
        {
            return
        }
        self.currentLocation = locations.first!
        let message = ["lat":self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,"long":self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]
        WatchConnector.shared.sendMessage(message, withIdentifier: "sendCurrentLocation") { (error) in
            print("error in send message to watch\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Fail to load location")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController{
    private let locationAccessUnauthorizedMessage = "Locations Disabled\n\nEnable locations for this app via the Settings in your iPhone to see meetups near you!"
    private let pendingAccessMessage = "Grant location access to GPS dummy"

    @IBOutlet weak var map: WKInterfaceMap!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: WKInterfaceButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var latitudeL: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var longitudeL: WKInterfaceLabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var authorizeL: WKInterfaceLabel!
    var currentLocation = CLLocation()
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var lat: Double = 0.0
    var long: Double = 0.0


    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        // Configure interface objects here.
    }


    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
        WatchConnector.shared.listenToMessageBlock({ (message) in

            self.lat = message["lat"] as! Double
            self.long = message["long"] as! Double
            print(self.lat)
            print(self.long)

            self.currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: self.lat as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: self.long as! CLLocationDegrees)

            let mylocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
            let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mylocation, span: span)
            self.map.setRegion(region)
            self.map.addAnnotation(mylocation, with: .red)
        }, withIdentifier: "sendCurrentLocation")

        let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        handleLocationServicesAuthorizationStatus(authorizationStatus)
    }

    func handleLocationServicesAuthorizationStatus(_ status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("handleLocationServicesAuthorizationStatus: .undetermined")
            handleLocationServicesStateNotDetermined()
        case .restricted, .denied:
            print("handleLocationServicesAuthorizationStatus: .restricted, .denied")
            handleLocationServicesStateUnavailable()
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("handleLocationServicesAuthorizationStatus: .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse")
            handleLocationServicesStateAvailable(status)
        }
    }

    func handleLocationServicesStateNotDetermined() {
        authorizeL.setText(pendingAccessMessage)
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func handleLocationServicesStateUnavailable() {
        authorizeL.setText(locationAccessUnauthorizedMessage)
    }

    func handleLocationServicesStateAvailable(_ status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .authorizedAlways:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager.requestLocation()
        default:
            break
        }
    }


    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }


    @IBAction func btnPressed() {
        self.latitudeL.setText("\(self.lat)")
        self.longitudeL.setText("\(self.long)")

        print("\(locationManager.requestLocation())")
        print("\(self.lat)")
        print("\(self.long)")
    }

}

extension InterfaceController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("error:: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.requestLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        if locations.first != nil {
            print("location:: (location)")
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on a simulator? If so, you might need to set the location to something in the Debug/Location menu:

[image]

Comment: I am testing on the real watch connected to the phone. Can I not get the current longitude and latitude?

Comment: Do you get a location permission prompt when first running the app?